# Can I expose CiviCRM contacts to Drupal Linkit?

Tags: drupal

We have an intranet for a small membership organization with a wiki done in Drupal 7 and a CiviCRM 4.5 installation for member information. Everyone with access to one has access to the other, so we looked into the idea of linking directly to CiviCRM contacts from the wiki as appropriate (e.g. "for ad hoc reports, contact Nilesh").

[Linkit](https://drupal.org/project/linkit) is a Drupal module that makes it easy to insert links into content, whether through a WYSIWYG editor or at the field level. To simplify, it provides an autocomplete field that allows the content author to choose from possible destinations, then automatically generates the canonical link. This would be ideal for authors, to avoid having to look up CiviCRM contact IDs.

According to the module page,

> Linkit links to nodes, users, managed files, terms and have basic support for **all entities by default**.

(emphasis in original). It does not, however, interface with CiviCRM contacts that should be recognized as Drupal entities when [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) is installed and active.

Is the fault here on CiviCRM Entity or on Linkit? Is there a better practice for linking CiviCRM contacts from CMS content?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a problem with Linkit. Test this with Entity Reference, if that works then LinkedIt may simply not have support for the CiviCRM entities by default (for some reason): https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the CiviCRM Contact Reference Field module?  It ships with Core but needs to be turned on separately.

Comment: Linkit is for creating hyperlinks in body text fields. As I understand it, CiviCRM Contact Reference is a separate kind of field altogether, and you couldn't use it to look up a contact and insert a link to the profile in the body.

Comment: Your post also stated "at the field level" and Angela is right that such a feature would be replicable using the Contact Reference Field module. If you figure that a fix is needed for CiviCRM Entity then pls supply a patch if at all possible